# Why is Log[8 E^(3 Log[0.5]) != 0

Tags: simplifying-expressions

My wife and I have tried to calculate Log[8 E^(3 Log[0.5]) on a TI-Nspire and we got the result -8E-14. We have changed th settings of calculation to Exact and the result was 0 (correct)

If I use Mathematica I got 2.22045*10^-16 as an approximation.

How can I use Mathematica to have the correct result of 0?

Thanks in advance.

Jörg

Comment: By writing 0.5, you are using machine precision numbers. Use 1/2 to use arbitrary precision numbers and the result will be exactly 0.

Comment: two ways. `Log[8 E^(3 Log[0.5])] // Chop` or `Log[8 E^(3 Log[Rationalize@0.5])]`